# MATLAB Genetic Algorithm : Distance of separation between solution points

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, genetic-algorithm

I need to optimize the location of 10 Transmitters and 10 Receivers (modeled as points on an aperture plane) so as to minimize a certain objective scalar using Genetic Algorithm toolbox in MATLAB. My question is: I have (10+10)*2 = 40 variables (optimizing x and y positions of each point). How do I model the constraints in the form Ax <= b, such that each point is separated by a minimum distance in both x and y directions from all other points?

Comment: As a follow-up, would it be better to implement that within the 'Create Function' field under Population in the Optimization toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

I'd model the objective function as the euclidian distance between the points, which you are trying to minimize. Also the transmitters and receivers must have a minimum distance between them. So this distance should be minimum, but greater than the minimum distance of the equipment. I'd look into the dimensions of the plane to identify all the constraints.

Comment: My objective is actually to maximize the spread of wavevectors corresponding to each Tx/Rx combination in the Fourier plane. I was hoping to model the separation between the points as constraints. Any way I could accommodate for that by a custom population generation?

Comment: @maxwellsapprentice sorry I won't be of much more help here... kinda rusty :z Hope you get some insights

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently creating my own function (modeled after the globaloptim library function gacreationlinearfeasible.m) that generates the population that satisfies the bounds, linear constraints and also my additional constraint, i.e. minimum distance of separation between the points. I think that should work.